# Using the C++ strstr function to remove the part of the substring your are searching for

Tags: c++, function, strcpy, strcat, strstr

I have an exercise question in class that has me stumped which is write a function named strCut that receives two C-style string parameters s and pattern. If the pattern string is contained in s, then the function modifies s such that the first occurrence of pattern that appears in s is removed from s.  To perform the pattern search, use the predefined strstr function.

Here is my code as of now.

```
void strCut(char *s, char *pattern)
{
  char *x;
  char *y;
  x = strstr(s, pattern);
  cout << x; // testing what x returns
}

int main()
{

  char s[100];        // the string to be searched
  char pattern[100];  // the pattern string
  char response;           // the user's response (y/n)

do
{
  cout << "\nEnter the string to be searched ==> ";
  cin.getline(s, 100);
  cout << "Enter the pattern ==> ";
  cin.getline(pattern, 100);
  strCut(s, pattern);
  cout << "\nThe cut string is \"" << s << '"' << endl;
  cout << "\nDo you want to continue (y/n)? ";
  cin >> response;
  cin.get();
} while (toupper(response) == 'Y');
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Since this appears to be homework I am only going to give a hint: `strstr` does half of the job.  The remainder of the job will be done by `memmove`.  (It may *appear* that `memcpy` or `strcpy` can also do that part, but that is incorrect.)  You will also need `strlen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function can be written for example the following way

```
char * strCut( char *s, const char *pattern )
{
   if ( char *p = std::strstr( s, pattern ) )
   {
      char *q = p + std::strlen( pattern );
      while ( *p++ = *q++ );
   }

   return s;
}
```

Or there could be used function `std::memmove` instead of the inner loop.

Comment: -1 `strcpy` has undefined behavior for overlapping strings.  Would -1 again for giving out complete answers to homework, (this has been scientifically demonstrated to inhibit learning), and -1 yet a third time for the abominable practice of putting spaces on the inside of parentheses, if only I could.

Comment: C11 section 7.24.2.3 (specification of `strcpy`): "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, *the behavior is undefined*."  Identical language for `memcpy`, `strncpy`, `strcat`, `strncat`.  Only `memmove` is valid for this use case.

Comment: If you acknowledge the error please correct the code so as not to mislead future readers.  (I will not retract the -1, though, because of the giving out complete answers to homework.)

Comment: @Zack I could write code manually in fact the same as the logic of strcpy.

Comment: @Zack Do you mean the first function definition?